# On logarithmic schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, semigroups-and-monoids

I have two questions on logarithmic schemes

1. Can we explicitly construct a chart for any coherent logarithmic scheme?  By definition of coherence it must have a chart but given a coherent sheaf of monoids M is it possible to construct a chart for example using its characteristics?
2. The second question is about log-stable curve. According to Fumiharu Kato's definition: A log curve $X\rightarrow S$ over any log scheme $S$ is called a log-stable curve if for every closed point $s\in S$,  $H^0(X_s,\omega^*_{_{X_s}})=0$, where $\omega^*_{_{X_s}}$ is the dual of the sheaf of relative log differentials. My doubt is that if we accept this definition then the underlying curve of a log-stable curve may not be stable according to the definition of "Deligne-Mumford", because then a log-stable curve can have many automorphisms. For example consider a semistable model of a usual stable curve. It has many automorphisms but there are no log-automorphisms. I don't know what i am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A strictly semistable curve fails to be stable because it has a "rational bridge," that is to say a component isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ that only meets the rest of the curve in $2$ points $p$ and $q$, meaning that it still has a $k^*$ worth of automorphisms. The derivative of such an automorphism is essentially a section of the tangent bundle (we impose zeroes at $p$ and $q$ so that this glues to the zero section on the other components). Put differently, we have $h^0(\mathbb P^1, T_{\mathbb P^1}(-p-q)) = h^0(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O) = 1$....

Comment: ...so a Deligne-Mumford semistable curve will not satisfy this condition. Now I don't know if this argument literally carries over to the log setting, but this should be the idea: a continuous group of automorphisms induces a vector field, and the dual of a sheaf of differentials should be something close to the tangent sheaf

Comment: 1. (I guess it depends on how explicit you want to get, but) yes, see for example Prop 2.1 here https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/lvs3.pdf .


2. the definition of stability for log curves corresponds indeed to stability for the underlying (non-log) curve - Corollary 1.15 here https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.37.1907&rep=rep1&type=pdf . (The confusing point here might be that the sheaf of log differentials incorporates the markings in the log setting...)

Comment: @Mattia Talpo Thanks for both the comments..I have a query regarding  the answer for the 2nd question. I don't understand what do you mean by "the sheaf of log differentials incorporates the markings in the log setting.". Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @Mattia Talpo  Because suppose $X$ be the semistable model of an stable curve $Y$ (no markings other than the nodes), and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be the stabilization map. Then $f^*\omega_Y\cong \omega_X$ and $f_*\mathcal O_X=\mathcal O_Y$. Using projection formula, one can show that $H^0(X, \omega_X^*)=  H^0(Y, \omega_Y^*)=0$. So according to F. Kato's definition $X$ is log stable but clearly not stable. Also in this case there are no markings other than the nodes.